# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

i publish my .net core application on IIS using `file system` , when i open the application in browser it wont connect to database and throw me below error (in console of firefox) , but if i run from VS 2019 it works fine without any error . Any help is really appreciated.

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44374/api/userLogin/?username=test&password=test. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`

This is my `appsetting` :

```
  "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "patientDB": "Data Source=DESKTOP-FE7Q19U\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MDSS;Integrated Security=True"
  }
}
```

This is my `launchsetting`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51911",
      "sslPort": 44374
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ReactC_MDSS": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my `startup`:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<patientDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("patientDB")));
           
            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });


   

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I try to add cors but somehow it not worked.

Comment: You could include two or more request from the same page.  When the browser requests the server, it checks whether it comes from the same source. If it comes from a different source will cause such a situation. The another reason is that the browser may have secure policy so that the request is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The cors-error on IIS is the same port as you are developing with (https://localhost:44374). Can you show the code for API-request in your react code? Are you really refering to the Apps base adress (i.e. 'api/userLogin/?username=test&password=test') or a hardcoded localhost-path ('https://localhost:44374/api/userLogin/?username=test&password=test')? The later will be blocked by the browser because of CORS-policy. But you can add an exception in Startup.cs

Comment: If the browser is on `https://localhost:44374/something` then a request to `https://localhost:44374/api/userLogin` shouldn’t trigger CORS, regardless of whether you are using a host-relative URL (`/api/userLogin`) or not.

Comment: i am using this             const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44374/api/userLogin/?username=' + document.getElementById("txtemail").value + '&password=' + document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;

Comment: @Andreas Sundström can you show where to put exception.

Comment: Okay so try using something like `const customerApi = 'api/userLogin/?username...` instead. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for how to allow CORS.

@poke No that's true but my guess is that he didn't configure his IIS to run on port 44374. Port 80 or 443 is more common (by default). And if he did run it on port 80/443 a request to https://localhost:44374 will be blocked by CORS by the browser.